# How to convert Http to ok http

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

i have used Http for network request but http is slow now i want to use okhttp instead of http how can i convert http to okhttp my code is below

```
public class Http {
public String postRequest(String endPoint, String body) {
    URL url;
    Log.d("Waseem", "Calling URL:" + endPoint);
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(endPoint);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //send data to server over the connection.
        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(body.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String responseLine;
        while ((responseLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"Response: "+responseLine);
            response += responseLine;
        }
        //Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"Response: "+response);

        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        //Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"Exception: "+exp.getMessage());
        exp.printStackTrace();
        response = "{\"result\":false,\"message\":\"Exception: " + exp.getMessage() + "\"}";

    }
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();

    }
    return response;
}
```

This is java activity from where i have made a http request how can change this code to ok http

```
 private Http http;
private String remoteMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    emailLogin= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailLog);
    passwordLogin= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassLog);

    http=new Http();
    login= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (emailLogin.getText().toString().length()>3 &&
                    passwordLogin.getText().toString().length()>4){

                emailText=emailLogin.getText().toString();
                passwordText=passwordLogin.getText().toString();

                new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        String response;
                        String body="email="+emailText+"&password="+passwordText;
                        response=http.postRequest(HttpConfigs.URL_AUTH,body);
                        return response;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                        super.onPostExecute(response);
                        try {
                            final JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
                            remoteMessage=responseJson.getString("message");
                            if (responseJson.getBoolean("result")){
                                showMessage(remoteMessage);
                                JSONObject data = responseJson.getJSONObject("data");
                                Log.d("WaseemTest","Data"+data);
                            }else{
                                showMessage(remoteMessage);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you read okhttp tutorials ?

Comment: `used Http for network request`. No. That is HttpUrlConnection. `but http is slow `. No. HttpUrlConnection is not slow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all import okhttp library

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
```

Then make a class of okhttp which you will call for every http request

```
public class InitializeBuilderOkhttp extends OkHttpClient{

OkHttpClient client;

public OkHttpClient returnInitializeBuilderOkhttp() {

    client = new OkHttpClient();
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client = builder.build();
    return client;

}
}
```

Please go through okhttp tutorial why the timeouts are as such in this case.You can change them to your liking.

Then in the activity,

```
OkHttpClient client;
client = new InitializeBuilderOkhttp().returnInitializeBuilderOkhttp();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlOrders+parameterStringBeforeEncoding+"&oauth_signature="+signature)
                .get()
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try{
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        }
        catch (ConnectException ex){
            //Toast.makeText(this_context,"Cannot connect to server at this time.Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //Log.d("output",""+result);
        if (response != null) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
```

This will be present in the async task "do in background" method.In your case, the request will be POST type.

For post type,

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
okhttp3.RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, postDataStringInJson);
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(urlOrders+parameterStringBeforeEncoding+"&oauth_signature="+signature)
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: is there is best tutorial on any site

Comment: @WaseemAbbas have given you a working code in my app.Though will give you a link to the tutorial.Give me a min

Comment: please briefly explain this code #debo.stackoverflow

Comment: @WaseemAbbas the import part you have understood. and the seperate class is just an initialization of the okhttp client object.Which part you havent understand?

Comment: @WaseemAbbas actually found this link from vogella which is latest . cite:- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html.  Can check from this link.If any doubt then tell me

Comment: @WaseemAbbas please check other sites for understanding how to import a 3rd party library from android studio.Basically from studio go to Build->Edit libraries and dependencies->click on green coloured "+" sign->library dependency->then search for  okhttp 3